# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy - is this a stateful firewall?

Tags: security, kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Is `NetworkPolicy` a stateful firewall?

For example, if I allow ingress from a certain IPs on certain ports, is the return traffic automatically allowed on ephemeral? Ditto for allowed egress.

How does this play with a default block policy in place?

Are there any other considerations here?

Answer (score 7):

NetworkPolicy is stateful and will allow an established connection to communicate both ways.

Comment: +Shai Katz, thanks. Could you please provide any references documenting that?

Comment: @IlyaAyzenshtok Take a look at https://github.com/networkpolicy/tutorial#what-is-stateful-policy-enforcement.